# Where do I put the .tld file so that the resulting JAR file built with maven2 is properly packaged?

Tags: java, jsp, maven-2, web-applications, jsp-tags

I currently have the following directory structure for my code:

```
src
|-- main
|   `-- java
|       `-- com
|           `-- upthescala
|               `-- tags
|                   `-- ViewProtectTag.java
|-- test
|-- pom.xml
|-- .project
|-- .classpath
`-- .hgignore
```

I want to include a tld file for my JSP tag, and I'm not sure where to package it. My initial thought is to add a `src/main/resources` directory and put `META-INF/viewprotect.tld` in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My initial thought is to add a src/main/resources directory and put META-INF/viewprotect.tld in there

And that's a good initial thought.

Comment: Struts and Jsp puts them in WEB-INF. What is the virtue of putting .tld files in `META-INF` instead?